# Perl - updating and merging data after merging threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, asynchronous

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758226/perl-turning-foreach-loop-to-a-multi-threaded-run) question and [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907848/perl-how-can-i-edit-the-structure-of-a-shared-clone) I asked, I got some suggestions.

tl;dr:

I'm trying to run a "foreach" loop asynchronously. Each iteration updates a few hashes independently. The problem is that the memory is kept with each thread and I didn't know how to unite it all together.

I got a few suggestions, but I had problem with almost each:

1. When tried the thread/fork, there was a problem with shared memory that I needed to update everything to be shared and you're allowed to assign only shared values to those hashes and it made a big mess... (If there's a way to share everything, even variables that would later be defined. that might be a solution)
2. When trying to write all the hashes to files (by json), all the blessing is gone and I need to bless everything from the top which is a big mess too...

Any ideas how can I do it easier/faster?

Comment: It would be easier to give help if you provided some code examples. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: "_bless_" ?  What is blessed? Are those objects that you create in threads, and would like to return to the main thread?  Is this work IO-bound (involve the filesystem a lot) or not?  -- Are your threads working mainly with files or "just" computing away?  Should really tell us more... the question is broad anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In some problems a common data structure must indeed be *shared* between different threads.

When this isn't necessary things are greatly simplified by simply returning from each thread, when `join`-ing, a reference to a data structure built in the thread during the run.  The main thread can then process those results (or merge them first if needed). Here is a simple demo

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);  # or use core Data::Dumper

use threads;

# Start threads.  Like threads->create(...)
my @thr = map { async { proc_thr($_) } } 1..3;

# Wait for threads to complete. If they return, that happens here
my @res = map { $_->join } @thr;

# Process results (just print in this case)
dd $_ for @res;
   
sub proc_thr { 
    my ($num) = @_; 

    # A convoluted example, to return a complex data structure
    my %ds = map { 'k'.$_ => [$_*10 .. $_*10 + 2] } 10*$num .. 10*$num+2;

    return \%ds;
}
```

This prints

```
{ k10 => [100, 101, 102], k11 => [110, 111, 112], k12 => [120, 121, 122] }
{ k20 => [200, 201, 202], k21 => [210, 211, 212], k22 => [220, 221, 222] }
{ k30 => [300, 301, 302], k31 => [310, 311, 312], k32 => [320, 321, 322] }
```

Now manipulate these returned data structures as suitable; work with them as they stand or merge them. I can't discuss that because we aren't told what kind of data need be passed around. This roughly provides for what was asked for, as far as I can tell.

Important notes

- Lots of threads? Large data structures to merge? Then this may not be a good way
- The word "*bless*" was mentioned, tantalizingly. If what you'd pass around are objects then they need be [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for that, in such a way that the main thread can reconstruct the object.

  Or, pass the *object's data*, either as a reference (as above), or by serializing it and passing the string; then the main thread can populate its own object from that data.

  Returning (`join`-ing) an object itself (so a reference like above, an object being a reference) doesn't seem to fully "protect your rights;" I find that at least some operator overloading is lost (even as all methods seem to work and data is accessible and workable).

  This is a whole other question, of passing objects around.<sup>†</sup>
- If the work to be done is I/O-bound (lots of work with the filesystem) then this whole approach (with threads) need be carefully reconsidered. It may even *slow it down*

Altogether -- we need more of a description, and way more detail.

---

<sup>†</sup>  This has been addressed on Stackoverflow. A couple of directly related pages that readily come to mind for me are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132795/passing-object-between-programs-running-under-different-perl-versions/61133461#61133461) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230087/how-to-read-values-assigned-inside-a-script-in-a-program-that-runs-that-script/62242517#62242517).

In short, objects can be serialized and restored using for example [Storable](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable). Pure [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) cannot do objects, while extensions can. On the other hand, pure JSON is excellent for serializing *data* in an object, which can then be used on the other end to populate an identical object of that class.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not commenting, we had holidays here :)
I've decided to move forward with another way (YAML and back to merging blessed hashes). The main reason is the first and second drawback you entered.